# jQuery AJAX Syntax for getting response

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm working on a simple AJAX request that calls a URL when a button is clicked. I've got the basics working successfully so that the GET request is made to the URL when the button is clicked and I've confirmed the GET request was made by checking the logs at the other server. Here's the simple request script:

```js
< script >
  $("#callContact1").click(function() {

    $.ajax({

      url: "https://www.server.com?type=makecall",
      data: {},
      method: "GET",
      success: function(data) {

      }

    });

  }); <
/script>
```

I'm now trying to show the response from the GET request in a hidden div in my html:

```html
<div id="ajaxResponse" class="alert alert-info text-center" role="alert" style="display:none">
  Callback Response
</div>
```

I've modified the script as follows:

```js
< script >
  $("#callContact1").click(function() {

      $.ajax({

        url: "https://www.server.com?type=makecall",
        data: {},
        method: "GET",
        success: function(data) {
          $('#ajaxResponse').html(data);
          $("#ajaxResponse").show();

        }
      });

      fail(function(xhr) {
          var httpStatus = (xhr.status);
          var ajaxError = 'There was an requesting the call back. HTTP Status: ' + httpStatus;
          console.log('ajaxError: ' + ajaxError);
          //make alert visible
          $('#ajaxResponse').html(ajaxError);
          $("#ajaxResponse").show();
        }

      }); <
    /script>
```

but I'm running into syntax errors which I can't seem to overcome. Basically I want to insert the response from the GET request which will include a simple text response for a successful request or an error if one was encountered.

Comment: Your `<script>` tag should not have spaces inside. what syntax error did you get? where?

Comment: @Dekel - that wasn't me, the stackoverflow site must have added them when I used the insert css/html/javascript widget to add these

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.then()` or jQuery `deferred.done()` if you use `.fail()`, which can be chained to `.then()`. Also closing `</script>` should on same line.

```
<script>
  $("#callContact1").click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "https://www.server.com?type=makecall",
            data: {},
            type: "GET"
          })
          .then(function(data) {
            $('#ajaxResponse').html(data).show();
          })
          .fail(function(xhr) {
              var httpStatus = (xhr.status);
              var ajaxError = 'There was an requesting the call back. HTTP Status: ' + httpStatus;
              console.log('ajaxError: ' + ajaxError); 
              //make alert visible 
              $('#ajaxResponse').html(ajaxError).show();
         })
    })
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

`fail` method is not defined in your code. You can use `deferred` [done](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/)/[fail](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.fail/) methods to attach success and fail callbacks:

```
<div id="ajaxResponse" class="alert alert-info text-center" role="alert" style="display:none"></div>

<script>
  $("#callContact1").click(function() {

  $.ajax({

    url: "https://www.server.com?type=makecall",
    data: {},
    method: "GET"
  }).done(function (data) {
      $('#ajaxResponse').html(data);
      $("#ajaxResponse").show();
  }).fail(function (xhr){
      var httpStatus = xhr.status;
      var ajaxError = 'There was an requesting the call back. HTTP Status: ' + httpStatus;
      console.log('ajaxError: ' + ajaxError);
      //make alert visible
      $('#ajaxResponse').html(ajaxError);
      $("#ajaxResponse").show();
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Add an explanation to your answer, otherwise it's just a piece of code.